# Can't run 'rails new' because of activesupport error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to start a new rails project, but every time I run `rails new`, I get an activesupport gem error. I uninstalled activesupport and reinstalled it, and it still won't work. I get the following error:
`Could not find 'activesupport' (= 5.0.1) - did find: [activesupport-5.1.1] (Gem::LoadError)`

and it comes with this stack trace:

```
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/LukasBarry/.gem/ruby/2.3.0:/Users/LukasBarry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/LukasBarry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/LukasBarry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1427:in `each'
    from /Users/LukasBarry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1427:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/LukasBarry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1409:in `activate'
    from /Users/LukasBarry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:68:in `block in gem'
    from /Users/LukasBarry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/LukasBarry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `gem'
    from /Users/LukasBarry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's very frustrating not being able to create a new project. I am also thinking at the moment that the gem is maybe in a wrong folder that is not along the file path being checked, but I can never find the correct terminal commands online to fix it.

Comment: Can you post your `Gemfile`?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't have a Gemfile yet, because the project hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Turns out I had to uninstall the rails gem and then reinstall it. Thanks!

I am going to leave this up because while searching for a solution, I found nothing on google or stackoverflow addressing this specific problem, so hopefully it can help out someone else.